# geocode argument in tweeteR package

Tags: r

The tweeteR package has a function that searches tweets based on specified geographic locations.

How granular is the *geoid* argument in the searchTwitter function? In other words, how close in proximity could I search tweets given a latitude and longitude?

Example:

```
tweets = searchTwitter("food", # this is the keyword
                       geocode = "38.878337,-77.100703, 1mi", # 1 mile radius
                       n = 20)
```

Comment: The documentation — <https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets> — is not clear, but they don't show a number below 1mi and — frankly — this is a pursuit fraught with peril since i suspect you won't be including error rates or uncertainty in the spurious findings these results will provide.

Comment: I suspect that this feature is not that accurate. I tried searching for my own location using my own tweet, but it couldn't pick up the correct location of where I actually made the tweet. It was about 8 miles off.